# Wear: Open my app with custom voice Start command, not working

Tags: android, wear-os, voice

Hi I'm following [Google documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided) to open a dummy App with the Start command but is not working for me.

I created a new default project using Android Studio wizard with a mobile and a wear module.

I didn't touch anything but 'android:label' of Wear Module manifest to "Hola" (hello in Spanish) and when I say "Iniciar Hola" ("Start Hello") Wear makes a google search with the "hola" keyword.

Wear module or mobile module aren't being launched.

What I'm missing :'( seems pretty easy from Google docs...

PS: I'm testing over BT on a wear device

**Mobile manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.basetis.wearapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Mobile Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Wear Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.basetis.wearapp" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WearActivity"
            android:label="Hola" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Wear Activity**

```
public class WearActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... the spanish word to Start an application is "Abrir" not "Iniciar", but on wear UI the menu entry to open apps is "Iniciar" so an applause for Google UX Team :'(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the voice commands are for launching apps on your phone, not launching a wear app.

I'm able to say "Start calculator" and it opens the calculator app on my phone.

What you could do is launch an activity on the phone and then that activity launches the wear app that you intended.

Comment: So you mean that if I put the activity label "hola" on the mobile side, app will be launched?

Comment: The mobile app would them be launched, in which you can then send a message to the watch to open a specific activity.

Comment: This is in error---voice commands can be used to start Wear apps also. https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided